# running mapbox.js cordova application on mobile device

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, mapbox, visual-studio-cordova

when i run the mapbox.js example in my cordova application using visual studio, it running and display the map correctly in visual studio emulator "simulate in browser-Nexus 4", if i run the same application apk file in my mobile device map is not loading.

The difference seems to be, in the example page on both, that the mapbox doesn't take up any difficulty in loading the map. The issue only appears to be an issue when running mapbox on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this question...
If we face the above problem means, we can  install whitelist plugin with Cordova CLI, from npm. In the Command Prompt, change directories to the "(your cordova project\bin)" folder

(For example:C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DemoProject\DemoProject\bin )

and run the following command.

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare

By using this, we can easily run the cordova.apk in our mobile devices